# Tripod accessory needed to allow for multiple mounts (stacked vertically/behind)

Tags: equipment-recommendation, lighting, tripod

I have a little tripod that has a mountable phone holder and light orb. Since the light orb is small, it's very convenient and I think it might also make a decent supplementary light source when I'm using my gopro to photograph (in cramped/remote places). However, I seem to be a few cards short of a full deck in that I can't combine the accessories together on the tripod. The gopro mount needs a 1/4" male, as does the bottom of the light orb (both circled in red) whereas the tripod just has the typical single 1/4" male (circled in green). See below:

[image]

I tried searching for "multiple mount" tripod accessories on a few search engines, but only saw products that were for professional setups (they were huge, meter-long horizontal bars). I'm looking for a simple Y-adapter of sorts, having one 1/4" female and providing two 1/4" males in a small form factor.

### Question

Are there any off-the-shelf solutions for my need case? If not, is there any refined DIY approaches other than grabbing some scrap wood and making a frankenstein adapter?

Comment: _is there any refined DIY approaches other than grabbing some scrap wood...?_ I don't understand that part of the question. I mean, _of course_ there are more refined approaches. 3D printing the needed part(s), die/laser cutting the parts, machining the parts, etc., are all more refined than cobbling together a solution from scrap wood.

Comment: One possible solution between "meter long bars" and "small", in case you need a bit more stability on a bigger tripod: Two foot-long 15/60 lws rods, one baseplate, two camera mounts (should be around $40-60 for everything).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PTQXS79).

If you want to find another one; i searched for "Flash bracket". A typical flash bracket is a rather short arm screwed under the camera with some way to attach a flash (flash bracket or screw). Just had to find one with a thread in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps search for "dual camera bracket" on a sales side or "stereo camera bracket".